# tags: chess-computers vs chess-engines?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I think people are more familiarized with the nonexistent [chess-engines](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess-engines) than with [chess-computers](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess-computers).

I propose to alias them up, and *maybe* use `chess-engines` as master tag.

Comment: Looks exactly like what tag aliasing was invented for. I'd probably even alias *computers* (I mean, there's no **chess-strategy** tag, tight ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you don't feel left hanging, I'm posting this as a notice that in a few days I'll default to a combination of ajax's and Nikana's suggestions, synonymizing the tags [chess-engines](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess-engines), [chess-computers](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess-computers), [engines](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engines) and [computers](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computers), and additionally making [engines](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engines) the master of these, unless objections to doing so are raised/supported here.

Comment: Can you add [computer-chess] as a synonym as well? I'm not able to do it due to not having a sufficient score in the tag.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to this exchange and missed this discussion, but I do have a strong objection to using `engines` as the master tag; it is misleading. Some questions are about specific chess-playing engines, or about comparing them. Use the `engines` tag for that.

Some questions are about more abstract computational concerns: are there promising AI algorithms? how many moves can we hope to compute in advance? I urge that this is reconsidered so we allow the more generic tag `computers` for these questions.

Comment: I believe `engines` is fine, maybe for those more computer-based questions we can use something like `computer-analysis` or `computer-evaluation`, I don't know, just throwing an opinion